# Iframe not displaying the PDF

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a link when pasted it would display as PDF

But when I embed in iframe its not displaying and refusing to connect.

I have tried with

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1s5kA0DXmxUGZ7Ydjk3Aa-wu7xhKyInM3s7p19XUfaFU/export/pdf?id=1s5kA0DXmxUGZ7Ydjk3Aa-wu7xhKyInM3s7p19XUfaFU&pageid=g9fbb3c24c3_0_71&attachment=false" title="IFRAME">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that, when ceratin URLS have a XFRAME as **sameorigin** they **don't** allow to embed via iframe. Its evident here.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have public access to view the pdf file. You can also use the Object tag to view pdf if the user has the pdf plugin installed. else it will display a Google doc file.

```html
<object data="https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true">
    <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</object>
```

Comment: There is access to the above file. When you paste the url it will work but when pasted in iframe if won't work that's my question and you have misunderstood

Comment: Nope, Please paste your URL into the browser incognito mode, and you will understand what I said about Access, also you can add "preview" instead of "edit or view" in your shared document URL like below

https://docs.google.com/file/d/XXXXXXXXXXX/preview?somevaluehere=abc

Comment: Your answer must have been XFRAME is set to SAMEORIGIN. Hence it wasnt displaying.